# How to bind my list of object to radio button in .net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a dummy model call Manufacture and I have a list of dummy data call model like shown below.

Here is my model:

```
Public class Manufacture
{
 public string ManufactureName { get; set; }
 public string somedata1 { get; set; }
 public string somedata2 { get; set; } 
 public string somedata3 { get; set; }
}
```

In Controller `HTTPGet` I am rendering a list to my View:

```
List<Manufacture> model = new List<Manufacture>
{
    new Manufacture(){ Name = "VW", somedata1="abc",somedata2="def",somedata3="ghi" },
    new Manufacture(){ Name = "BMW", somedata1="jkl",somedata2="mno",somedata3="pqr" },
    new Manufacture(){ Name = "Audi", somedata1="stu",somedata2="vwx",somedata3="y&z" },
};

return View(model);
```

In my View I have something like this to list each ManufactureName as a radio button:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Manufacture.Count; i++)
{
   <div>
        <label>
            @Html.RadioButton("selectedManufacture", Model.Manufacture[i].ManufactureName)
            @Model.Manufacture[i].ManufactureName
        </label>
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Manufacture[i].somedata1);
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Manufacture[i].somedata2);
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Manufacture[i].somedata3);
}
```

In my controller HTTPPost method I have something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChooseYourCarManufacture(Manufacture model, string selectedManufacture)
{
    ...
}
```

With this `HTTPPost` method I am able to detect which ManufactureName was selected by using the `selectedManufacture` but I am unable to bind that to the object in the list of Manufacture. i.e. I want a better way to determine which ManufactureName was selected so I can then easily render to screen all the `data properties` about that manufacture. How can I do that?

Comment: Try LINQ to pass selected manufacture to view all property values: `listManufacture.Where(x => x.ManufactureName == selectedManufacture).ToList();` (make sure that `listManufacture` contains items from `List<Manufacture>` first).

Comment: yup. that exactly what i have done. But I was looking for how to integrate it directly by binding the model